# Eps figures are not diplaying?

Tags: graphics, texmaker, eps, epstopdf

I am using texmaker and I include eps figures. The code is very long but I will include some of it.

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{./Figures/RL_NE.eps}
\caption{Percentage of playing good}
\label{fig_1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I open my compiled file I will get the following:
[image]

I do not know where is the problem. I am compiling with PdfLatex.

Comment: you have `[draft]` option set

Comment: yes I have. I must remove it in order to see the figure?

Comment: edtit that fragment to be a complete document (just adding the few extra lines necessary eg `\documentclass` and `\end{docuemnt}` and check that _that file_ has the problem. If it does not, the problem is in a part of your real document that you have not shown

Comment: yes draft speeds things up (by quite a lot back in 1994) by _not_ including the figure

Comment: Alright, I edited the necessary lines. Thank you David Carlisle.

Comment: I'm sure this must be a duplicate but I don't see a good copy yet

Comment: Someone deleted my comment -_- .